# Simple recursive web crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I made a simple web crawler, I know there's many better ones out there, but I thought rolling my own would be a valuable learning experience.

The problem is that I think there's some things I could improve here. I commented the code best I could to explain what it's doing:

```
import re, random, requests, threading, collections, queue

class Crawler():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = set() # this will store our crawled urls, avoiding duplicates
        self.terminate = False # flag to end the program
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.print_queue = queue.Queue() # this is for our prints
        self.work = collections.defaultdict(int) # store some data about the work done (number of urls stored) by each worker

    def run(self, threads=15, limit=1000, urls=()):
        if(not urls): print('[-] Provide start urls'); return # one of the ways ternary operator in python, ';' if continue in same line
        self.urls_max = limit # each thread is killed when we have 1000 urls stored
        for i, url in enumerate(urls): # placing the threads, 15 for each url by default
            for j in range(threads):
                tName = '{}.{}'.format(i+1, j+1)
                t = threading.Thread(target=self.producer, args=(url,), name=tName)
                t.start()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.print_manager)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        del t

    def wait_kill_threads(self): # waits for all the threads are killed
        while(threading.active_count() > 2): # main thread (this one) count as 1 and deamon too
            continue

    def print_manager(self): # our deamon to print
        while True:
            msg = self.print_queue.get()
            print(msg)
            self.print_queue.task_done()

    def renew_url(self, list_urls): # choose another url to work with
        return random.choice(list_urls)

    def worker(self): # get the thread details
        return threading.currentThread()

    def get_work_done(self):
        self.wait_kill_threads()
        return self.work

    def get_data(self): # our final data
        self.wait_kill_threads()
        return self.data

    def get_links(self, url):
        req = self.get_req(url)
        if(req is not None):
            html = req.text # the html of the page crawled
            urls = re.findall('(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', html) # extracting a list with the urls
            return urls
        return []

    def get_req(self, url):
        if(self.terminate): return None
        with requests.Session() as s:
            try:
                headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1'}
                return s.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=2)
            except Exception as e:
                self.print_queue.put('[-] Thread {} [-] Error getting page: {} [-] ERROR: {}'.format(self.worker().getName(), url, e))
                return self.get_req(self.renew_url(list(self.data)))

    def verify_and_add(self, url):
        with self.lock:
            len_data = len(self.data)
            self.terminate = len_data >= self.urls_max # true if we reach the self.urls_max, 1000 by default
            if(not self.terminate):
                if(url not in self.data):
                    self.data.add(url) # add to urls crawled
                    self.work[self.worker().getName()] += 1 # plus 1 on work done by this thread
                    response = '[+] Total stored: {: <4} [+] Thread {: >5} [+] {: <4} urls stored [+] putting: {}'
                    self.print_queue.put(response.format(len_data+1, self.worker().getName(), self.work[self.worker().getName()], url))
                    return True
        return False


    def inject_links(self, url):
        if(self.terminate): return
        urls = self.get_links(url) # get all links from a page
        for url in urls:
            if(not self.verify_and_add(url)): # check if url already exists on our set of urls, if false we will crawl another random one from our set
                if(self.terminate): return
                change_urls = list(set(urls) - self.data) # eles that are in urls but not in data
                if change_urls: # check if we have some new urls to scrape
                    return self.inject_links(self.renew_url(change_urls)) # repeat with the new url
                return self.inject_links(self.renew_url(list(self.data))) # if we dont have any new url lets a get a random from our data
        return

    def producer(self, url):
        while(not self.terminate): # this is the trigger to stop all threads
            self.inject_links(url)
            url = self.renew_url(list(self.data)) # start with another random url on our data
            continue
        with self.lock: # LOCK THIS BLOCK
            response = '[+] killing thread {: >5} [+] {: <4} urls stored [+] waiting for {: >3} threads to finish'
            self.print_queue.put(response.format(self.worker().getName(), self.work[self.worker().getName()], threading.active_count()-3)) # -3 because mainthread and deamon thread

crawler = Crawler()
target_urls = ('http://stackoverflow.com/', 'http://edition.cnn.com/', 'https://www.reddit.com/')
crawler.run(threads=15, limit=1000, urls=target_urls)
data = crawler.get_data()
print('\nyap got', len(data))
```

You can also had this at the end of the code to check in detail the best/worst work done:

```
workers = crawler.get_work_done()
work_items = workers.items()
print('Work done, total urls stored by thread: ', dict(workers))
print('yap got {} of work done (sum of all workers stored urls)'.format(sum(workers[i] for i in workers)))
best_worker, max_urls_stored = max((i for i in work_items), key=lambda x: x[1])
MVPS = [i for i in workers if workers[i] == max_urls_stored]
print('And the best workers are: {} with {} urls stored'.format(MVPS, max_urls_stored))
worst_worker, min_urls_stored = min((i for i in work_items), key=lambda x: x[1])
LVPS = [i for i in workers if workers[i] == min_urls_stored]
print('And the worst workers are: {} with {} urls stored\n'.format(LVPS, min_urls_stored))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.- Yes, you can use semicolon to have more than one sentence in the same line, but..

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are
>   generally discouraged.

```
if(not urls): print('[-] Provide start urls'); return # one of the ways ternary operator in python, ';' if continue in same line
```

Source: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

2.- Wait some milliseconds all those `while True:` (ie: `wait_kill_threads`, `print_manager`, maybe in `producer` too) your processor will thank you.

---

3.- Avoid [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) or [Hardcoded numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding). On the last line in `producer`:

```
.....threading.active_count()-3))   # -3 because mainthread and deamon thread
```

a better practice is use a CONSTANT_VALUE at the beginning of the file;

```
QTY_THREAD_OFFSET = 3

.....threading.active_count() - QTY_THREAD_OFFSET))
```

(maybe you can think in a better constant name, but you get the idea right?)

The same for:

```
while(threading.active_count() > 2): # main thread (this one) count as 1 and deamon too
```

using the previous const it will be:

```
while(threading.active_count() >= QTY_THREAD_OFFSET):
```

---

4.- Regex: If you are going to use a regex multiple times a good practice is compile the regex before. Instead of:

```
re.findall('(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', html) # extracting a list with the urls
```

you can do this:

```
URL_RE_PATTERN = '(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])'
...
class Crawler():
    regex_urls = re.compile(URL_RE_PATTERN)

    def __init__(self):
    ...    

...
...
def get_links(self, url):
....
    urls = urls_re.match(regex_urls)
```

Also you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to get urls.

---

5.- In `verify_and_add` you can try to avoid nested if's:

```
if(not self.terminate):
    if(url not in self.data):
        self.data.add(url) #
```

It could be replaced by:

```
if self.terminate or url in self.data:
    return False

self.data.add(url)
...
```

---

6.- A little detail:

```
if(req is not None):
```

It could be:

```
if req:
```

-- Edit:
As Guimo pointed out, the previous sentences are not equal.

So I would suggest to change

```
def get_links(self, url):
    req = self.get_req(url)
    if(req is not None):
        html = req.text # the html of the page crawled
        urls = re.findall('(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', html) # extracting a list with the urls
        return urls
    return []
```

by

```
def get_links(self, url):
    req = self.get_req(url)
    if req is None:
        return []

    html = req.text # the html of the page crawled
    urls = re.findall('(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', html) # extracting a list with the urls
    return urls
```

Ie, remove parenthesis and an [early return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement).

---

7.- Are you removing the visited urls from list_urls after is visited? In `renew_url` you are getting a random url but I can't see if you are removing it from that list.

---

8.- Wait some random secs between requesting pages on the same server, you are crawling a website most of them aren't happy with that.

---

That is what I see in a first approach! Hope it helps !

Comment: About number 6, note that they are not equivalent: suppose req is an empty list (or anything that evaluates to "False" apart from None). The first one will evaluate to "if True" and the second one will evaluate to "if False". Related to this, I recommend looking for information about `__nonzero__()` function. Also, no need to write parenthesis, you could go with ''if req is not None:`.

Comment: @Guimo; Thanks for the feedback! you are right!

Comment: Thanks for all advices, nice ones, good call on the regex

Answer (score 0):

About number 7, all urls will be distinct because of :
"self.data = set() # this will store our crawled urls, avoiding duplicates"

Comment: Is this in response to [the answer by mayo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/154857/120114)? If so, this should not be an answer to [the original question by Mayo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/154687/120114).... it would be appropriate to comment on the answer by Mayo but you will need to earn 50 reputation points first...